# Git is very slow

Tags: git

I am using now git in Windows 10, and when I try any command it takes lot of time. This is only the case in my office network. 
At home, everything work fine as it should be. Is there any extra configuration has to be done?

Comment: "Git Flow" is just a naming convention for branches, isn't it? It's not an app.

Comment: It is a convention for branches which is implemented and accessible through git bash for example

Comment: The Gitflow Workflow defines a strict branching model designed around the project release.

Comment: my situation is that my computer memory is high (98%)
after the memory goes down to about 50~60 %
git works nomrally

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact that maybe you are behind a corporate proxy, also you cat try in your Git Bash to do `echo $HOME` and you should see different results when you are on the office network and on your home network, you can change this variable directly in git bash using: `export HOME=\c\Users\<desired_path>` (keep in mind this change will not be persistent).

Also a good thing is to check if your PATH has unnecessary things in it, which can slow things down:

Windows cmd: `set %PATH%`

Git Bash: `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

This helpt me.

Uninstall git-bash. Remove the ..\program files\Git directory.
Then reinstall by running the installer as administrator.